# .NET Core 3.1 Login confusion with User Name / Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Evening all,
I am using .NET Core 3.1 to design a website and have the requirements to have the user login.
I have used the scaffold identity to create the login page and have added the AspNetUsers table (and other tables) using the package manager add-migration / update database to a SQL database. I was having a play with the SQL table and decided that I wanted to update the user name from the email address to an actual user name.

I change the data in the table to this [SQL user failed login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi6mi.png) and try to log in and I get an Invalid login attempt.  If I change the data to [SQL user successful login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvxjf.png) it works fine and allows me to log in... Is this something I have done wrong, or something I need to change? I can provide any other info needed.

**EDIT**
In response to @Crowcoder I have tried this code

```
        private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManger;

        public IndexModel( PortalContext ContextDb,SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager )
        {
            _contextDb = ContextDb;
            _signInManger = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if ( !ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                return Page();
            }

            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync( User );
            user.UserName = "Test User";

            var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync( user );

            await _signInManger.RefreshSignInAsync( user );

            return RedirectToPage();
        }
```

But the result returns `{Failed : InvalidUserName}`
I have also tried `var result = await _userManager.SetUserNameAsync( user , "Test User" );` but with the same error.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong or an example?

Comment: You should always use the [UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn613290(v=vs.108)) to manipulate users. I'm not sure what consequences there are of directly changing those table values. Maybe none, or maybe it is the reason for your problem.

Comment: See duplicate: login uses the normalized column, as you've found out. The non-normalized one is just for display purposes. See also https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/fcab188c61bbced0f523292cfc9d4accc438122a/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs#L250 So if you want to update a user's username, normalize their new name and store that in the normalized column as well.

Comment: You use `UserManager.UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync()` to normalize the new user name. @Crowcoder you're linking to very old documentation, and OP already _is_ using the UserManager to update their user.